# SQL Server : 8K limit error with only 4 columns

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I have a table with following columns:

1. uniqueidentifier
2. nvarchar(100)
3. 500+ decimal(23,10)

After I tried to add one more decimal field, I got the SQL Server 8K limit error.

So I deleted all `decimal` columns except of 2. But if I try to insert a record (`nvarchar` column filled with 8 characters), I still get the 8K limit error.

> Cannot create a row of size 8070 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

How is that possible if the table has only 4 columns:

1. uniqueidentifier
2. nvarchar(100)
3. decimal(23,10)
4. decimal(23,10)

Comment: possible duplicate of [maximum row size exceeded when copying varbinary(max) field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701298/maximum-row-size-exceeded-when-copying-varbinarymax-field)

Comment: You need to rebuild the table after dropping fixed width columns as they still consume space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rebuild the table after dropping or adding a fixed width column as Martin suggested in comments.

```
ALTER TABLE [Your_Table_Name] REBUILD;
```

Please follow this [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2009/02/19/why-should-i-rebuild-a-table-after-dropping-or-adding-a-column/) for detailed explanation.